# Classifying space of real line bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, classifying-spaces

I have read that $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ is the classifying space of real line bundles. But I don't understand what that means. From all I know, a classifying space refers to a group. Is this meant to be the Picard Group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that for $X$ a (reasonable) topological space, the set $[X, \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}]$ of homotopy classes of maps $X \to \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ can be put in natural bijection with the set of real line bundles on $X$. More generally there is a [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) $BG$ of [principal $G$-bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle) for $G$ a topological group, and this one is the special case $G = GL_1(\mathbb{R})$, or equivalently (as it turns out) $G = O(1) = C_2$.

Comment: Thank you, and do you know what the respective classifying map is?

Comment: Ah, ignore what I said previously, I think something like it should work but I can't confidently claim to understand the details. I don't know an easy way to write down the classifying map given the bundle in general.